# 4 pre-destined parts of life in islam - death, wealth

Tags: hadith, nikah, death, reference-request

I recall, and do not know from where, that there are 4 areas of life that are pre written - Death, wealth, marriage and another that I can't remember..Is this the case and if so, is there any reference to this in the Quran and hadith?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you refer to the hadith saying:

> Verily your creation is on this wise. The constituents of one of you are collected for forty days in his mother's womb in the form of blood, after which it becomes a clot of blood in another period of forty days. Then it becomes a lump of flesh and forty days later Allah sends His angel to it with instructions concerning **four things**, so the angel writes down **his livelihood**, his **death**, his **deeds**, his **fortune and misfortune**. By Him, besides Whom there is no god, that one amongst you acts like the people deserving Paradise until between him and Paradise there remains but the distance of a cubit, when suddenly the writing of destiny overcomes him and he begins to act like the denizens of Hell and thus enters Hell, and another one acts in the way of the denizens of Hell, until there remains between him and Hell a distance of a cubit that the writing of destiny overcomes him and then he begins to act like the people of Paradise and enters Paradise.
>   (See for example in [Sahih al-Bukahri](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/80), [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/46/1) from which I'm quoting and [2nd](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/60/7) and [3rd](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/6/23) version in Sahih al-Bukhari and in other Sunnah compilation)

So the four things which are written while we are still in our mothers womb are:

1. our deeds
2. our livelihood
3. our death
4. and whether we are happy or unhappy.

there's no mentioning about our marriage in these ahadith. And I guess you meant livelihood (rizq) instead of wealth.